# What actions we need to allow in an IAM user policy to be able to perform Get/Set operations on Elasticache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to create a policy where users will have an ability to access the elasticache service to set and get entries from the redis instances . What actions should be allowed for the user so that it is able to perform those actions ?

is. `elasticache:ModifyCacheCluster`enough to provide users with such ability or is it too wide in terms of permission ? Any help woud be great .

Answer (score 2):

`elasticache:ModifyCacheCluster` is not for command related restrictions. What you need is
[Authenticating users with Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.RBAC.html#Access-string) which can be used with `Amazon ElastiCache for Redis 6.x`.

While creating users `access-string` will be the one that you will use to restrict commands on the given users. While creating `access-string` please check this [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/acl#acl-rules) to how to restrict commands. it could be something like this;

```
-@all +get +set
```

This part of the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/acl#playings-with-command-categories) has some examples, but i didn't try it on production.